# A delivery loop was detected which causes this email to be undeliverable when using a domain alias with Google Apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

This is a follow-on to the question "[How can I add an email alias to a domain alias in Google Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482413/how-can-i-add-an-email-alias-to-a-domain-alias-in-google-apps#)"

A primary domain has been successfully set-up with Google Apps (not G Suite) e.g. domain1.com

A secondary domain alias to the primary domain has also been setup. It has been verified e.g. domain2.com.

Although I successfully receive an email that is sent to bill@domain1.com, the error message "A delivery loop was detected which causes this email to be undeliverable" is received when an email is sent to bill@domain2.com.

It has been [24 hours](https://support.google.com/a/forum/AAAA034zvV8rkvNOouxZEA/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2FApps%2FrkvNOouxZEA%2FbiGLTi_YCgAJ&msgid=biGLTi_YCgAJ) since the domain alias was added.

Is there any additional step that must be completed?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I'm facing the exact same issue and its been more than 24 hours since I added the domain.

Comment: @VivekThomas - Yes, I was able to. It took more than 24 hours however less than 48 hours for the domain name to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

This has wasted a good couple of hours of my day today.

Log in to your Admin account at admin.google.com

Users / *Problem User* / User Information / Email Routing

In RED it says End-user routing has been discontinued. You can manage destinations using recipient mapping. You can also create an address list used to prevent routing rules from applying to specific users.

It offers a button to clear End-user routing. I have no idea where this end user routing came from because the account had never been used before today!

Clearing "end-user routing" made the loop go away.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but don't see any such button on that page.

Comment: Is this the recipient or sender address?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was as follows:

- Log in to your Admin account at admin.google.com
- Go to: Users / Problem User / User Information / Alternative email addresses (email alias)
- Add aliases with the secondary domain. Eg. info@secondarydomain.com, etc.

Emails to the secondary aliases should then arrive in your primary domain inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but with Google Domains forwarding. It turns out that clicking the big red button "Restore Google Workspace Records" on the Domains/Email page (which I did) adds DNS rules that interfere with Domains forwarding rules.

To remove Google Workspace DNS rules:

- Visit https://domains.google.com/registrar/mydomain/dns (replace "mydomain" with your domain)
- Scroll down and click Google Workspace to select the relevant DNS rules
- Click "Delete" next to "Manage"

To re-insert the Google Domains email forwarding records:

- click Email on the left side
- from the yellow banner, click **Enable email forwarding only**

These changes can take minutes and up to 24-48 hrs to fully propagate.